# Adding Acumatica Customer Contacts

Tags: web-services, acumatica

I am having problem adding customer contacts using web services, at first instance of integration my application successfully adds the contacts using web services. But when i re-integrate the same contact in the same customer it duplicates the previously integrated contacts instead of just updating them. I tried adding value to the ContactID field but it gives me the error of convert failed from string to int.

```
AR303000Content custSchema = context.AR303000GetSchema();
                        var commands = new Acumatica_LSOne_Integration.ARMODULE.Command[]
                        {
                            new Acumatica_LSOne_Integration.ARMODULE.Value 
                            {
                                Value = RecID.Replace("-"," ").Trim(), 
                                LinkedCommand = custSchema.CustomerSummary.CustomerID 
                            },

                            custSchema.Actions.NewContact
                        };
                        context.AR303000Submit(commands);

                        CR302000Content contSchema = context.CR302000GetSchema();
                        commands = new Acumatica_LSOne_Integration.ARMODULE.Command[]
                        {                                
                            new Acumatica_LSOne_Integration.ARMODULE.Value {Value = reader1.GetString(reader1.GetOrdinal("CONTACTNAME")).Trim(), LinkedCommand = contSchema.DetailsSummary.LastName}, 
                            new Acumatica_LSOne_Integration.ARMODULE.Value {Value = reader1.GetString(reader1.GetOrdinal("STREET")).Trim(), LinkedCommand = contSchema.DetailsAddress.AddressLine1},
                            new Acumatica_LSOne_Integration.ARMODULE.Value {Value = reader1.GetString(reader1.GetOrdinal("ADDRESS")).Trim(), LinkedCommand = contSchema.DetailsAddress.AddressLine2},
                            new Acumatica_LSOne_Integration.ARMODULE.Value {Value = reader1.GetString(reader1.GetOrdinal("CITY")).Trim(), LinkedCommand = contSchema.DetailsAddress.City},
                            new Acumatica_LSOne_Integration.ARMODULE.Value {Value = reader1.GetString(reader1.GetOrdinal("COUNTRY")).Trim(), LinkedCommand = contSchema.DetailsAddress.Country},
                            new Acumatica_LSOne_Integration.ARMODULE.Value {Value = reader1.GetString(reader1.GetOrdinal("ZIPCODE")).Trim(), LinkedCommand = contSchema.DetailsAddress.PostalCode},
                            new Acumatica_LSOne_Integration.ARMODULE.Value {Value = reader1.GetString(reader1.GetOrdinal("EMAIL")).Trim(), LinkedCommand = contSchema.DetailsContact.Email},
                            new Acumatica_LSOne_Integration.ARMODULE.Value {Value = reader1.GetString(reader1.GetOrdinal("PHONE")).Trim(), LinkedCommand = contSchema.DetailsContact.Phone1},
                            new Acumatica_LSOne_Integration.ARMODULE.Value {Value = reader1.GetString(reader1.GetOrdinal("CELLULARPHONE")).Trim(), LinkedCommand = contSchema.DetailsContact.Phone2},
                            contSchema.Actions.Save,
                        };
                        context.CR302000Submit(commands);
```

Comment: Please Add your code for a better understanding.

Comment: hi hybridzz, above is my code

Comment: Hi Angelo, You are submitting action with NewContact Action, After that if the contact is an existing contact, can you submit the CR302000 with the ContactID [NO SAVE ACTION], so that it will load the existing data to the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you are using Screen ID's AR303000 and CR302000,

- After you add the command for action "Add Contact" in customer schema
  and submit
- You may use the screen CR302000 and **set the ContactID and submit**
  first to load all information(if exists) to the schema
- later you add commands for the update of required values and **submit
  with save command**.

Comment: i've tried doing this but it gives me the error `Error #13: Inserting  Lead/Contact record raised one or more errors. Please review. Error: Display Name may not be empty. Error: Last Name may not be empty. ---> PX.Data.PXOuterException: Error #13: Inserting  Lead/Contact record raised one or more errors. Please review. `

Comment: The above steps mentioned is for updating the existing record, so you should submit the AR303000 with just the contactID, The error looks like you are trying to set the contactID  which is not existing with save command.

Comment: `AR303000Content c= context.AR303000GetSchema();
var com = new Command[]
{
 new Value {Value = RecID, LinkedCommand = custSchema.CustomerSummary.CustomerID },
        custSchema.Actions.NewContact
};
context.AR303000Submit(com);`

Comment: `CR302000Content c1= context.CR302000GetSchema();
com = new Command[]
{                                
 new Value {Value = vContactName, LinkedCommand = contSchema.ContactSummary.ContactIDDisplayName},
};
context.CR302000Submit(com);                                                        

com = new Command[]
{                                                                
 new Value {Value = vAdd, LinkedCommand = contSchema.DetailsAddress.AddressLine1},
        contSchema.Actions.Save,
};
context.CR302000Submit(com);`

Comment: hybridzz above are my code what could the problem here?

Comment: Sorry, i wrongly mentioned screen id as AR303000, it should be CR302000.. In your first command, you are opening the required customer by providing the existing ID, then you are clicking the NewContact button. In the next  step, if it is an existing contact set the existing contactID and CR302000Submit then you create command set for other values + save and do CR302000Submit to update. If you are creating a new contact, the code you mentioned above should work.

Comment: The above code you posted as comment will keppon creating new contacts, am i rite?

Comment: yes its creating new contacts, does it mean that i have to pass the Integer value on the ContactID instead of the ContactIDDisplayName?